# What do the vim script installation instructions "uncomment the option" refer to (in this circumstance)

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get syntax highlighting in vim for sqlite3. The [tcl_sqlite.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/tcl_sqlite.vim) The install details are:
     Place in ~/.vim/syntax/

```
Activated by uncommenting the option at the top of the tcl.vim file.
```

I have the [tcl.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1603) file in the my ~/.vim/syntax/

Which lines do i uncomment? What is the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines 19-29 from tcl.vim are:

> ```
> " Highlight Options: restart vim, after changing these options.
> " let s:tcl_highlight_namespace_bold = 1
> " let s:tcl_highlight_bookends = 1
> " let s:tcl_highlight_primary = 1
> " let s:tcl_highlight_expressions = 1
> " let s:tcl_highlight_variables = 1
> " let s:tcl_highlight_secondary = 1
> " let s:tcl_highlight_options = 1
> " let s:tcl_highlight_lcs_are_warnings = 1
> " let s:tcl_comments_ignore_nested_braces = 1
> let s:tcl_highlight_all = 1
> ```

`"` at the beginning of a line means it's commented out. It looks like `s:tcl_highlight_all` is enabled by default so you shouldn't have to do anything unless you want to cherry-pick which things to highlight, in which case you'd uncomment those lines instead.